# Running into R error with matching data frame columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have one data frame that looks like (gwas.data):

```
              SNP CHR        BP A1 A2 zscore      P CEUmaf    MAF
1       rs1000000  12 125456933  A  G  1.441 0.1496 0.3729 0.2401
563090 rs10000010   4  21227772  T  C  0.068 0.9455  0.575 0.4934
563091 rs10000023   4  95952929  T  G  1.217 0.2236 0.5917 0.3852
563092  rs1000003   3  99825597  A  G -0.306 0.7597  0.875 0.1794
563093 rs10000033   4 139819348  T  C  1.050 0.2935 0.4917 0.4789
2      rs10000037   4  38600725  A  G  0.072 0.9428 0.2833 0.2296
```

I have another that looks like (correct orientation):

```
        CHR        SNP A1 A2    MAF NCHROBS
6952148  12  rs1000000  A  G 0.2401     758
2272221   4 rs10000010  C  T 0.4934     758
2524810   4 rs10000023  G  T 0.3852     758
1838654   3  rs1000003  G  A 0.1794     758
2675630   4 rs10000033  C  T 0.4789     758
2338861   4 rs10000037  A  G 0.2296     758
```

I'm trying to right a program that takes replaces the gwas.data$MAF with (1-MAF) if A1 and A2 and switched between the two data frames. I'm trying to use this line of code here that I am borrowing from someone else:

```
    flip <- gwas.data$A1 == correct.orientation$A2 & gwas.data$A2 == correct.orientation$A1
    dont.flip <- gwas.data$A1 == correct.orientation$A1 & gwas.data$A2 == correct.orientation$A2

    for ( i in 1 : nrow ( gwas.data ) ) {
        if ( flip [ i ] ) {
            gwas.data$A1 [ i ] <- correct.orientation$A1 [ i ]
            gwas.data$A2 [ i ] <- correct.orientation$A2 [ i ]
            gwas.data$zscore [ i ] <- - gwas.data$EFF [ i ]
            gwas.data$MAF [ i ] <- 1 - gwas.data$FRQ [ i ]
        } else if ( dont.flip [ i ] ) {
            #do nothing
        } else {
            stop ( "Strand Issue")      
        }
```

I'm running into the error at the first line `flip <- gwas.data$A1 == correct.orientation$A2 & gwas.data$A2 == correct.orientation$A1` The error is 
`Error in Ops.factor(gwas.data$A1, correct.orientation$A2) : level sets of factors are different` How to fix this?

Comment: Can you please add the output of `dput gwas.data[1:6,]` and `dput correct.orientation[1:6,]` to your question so that we can see the exact data types and levels together with the example data? Thx!

Comment: The first guess is that the data columns use factors. Another (performance relevant) improvement should be: Replace the `for` loop over the rows with the vectorized `ifelse` function.

Comment: What does using factors mean and how can that be fixed?

Comment: also `dput gwas.data[1:6,]` gave me an `Error: unexpected symbol in dput gwas.data[1:6,]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider  forgoing the use of `for` loop and use the base R [merge()](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/merge) function of both dataframes. However, a little data management is needed: 1) temporarily convert factors to characters (or use `stringAsFactors=FALSE` in `read.csv()` or `read.table()`) and 2) adding suffixes for repeat column names. Once calculated MAF is complete with `ifelse()`, split the merged data frame and reset column names and data types to original structure:

```
# CONVERT FACTORS TO CHARACTER
gwas.data[, c("A1","A2")] <- sapply(gwas.data[,c("A1","A2")],as.character)
# SUFFIXING COL NAMES TO IDENTIFY IN MERGED DF
names(gwas.data) <- paste0(names(gwas.data), "_A")

# CONVERT FACTORS TO CHARACTER
correct.orientation[, c("A1","A2")] <- sapply(correct.orientation[,c("A1","A2")],as.character)
# SUFFIXING COL NAMES TO IDENTIFY IN MERGED DF
names(correct.orientation) <- paste0(names(correct.orientation ), "_B")

# MERGE DATA FRAMES (ASSUMING SNP IS UNIQUE IDENTIFIER)
comparedf <- merge(gwas.data, correct.orientation, by.x="SNP_A", by.y="SNP_B", all=TRUE)

# CALCULATE NEW MAF
comparedf$MAF_A <- ifelse(((comparedf$A1_A == comparedf$A2_B) &
                           (comparedf$A2_B == comparedf$A1_A)), 
                          (1 - comparedf$MAF_A), 
                          comparedf$MAF_A)
comparedf$zscore_A <- ifelse(((comparedf$A1_A == comparedf$A2_B) &
                              (comparedf$A2_B == comparedf$A1_A)),   
                               -1 * comparedf$zscore_A, 
                               comparedf$zscore_A)

# SPLIT MERGE BACK TO ORIGINAL STRUCTURE
newgwas.data <- comparedf[,names(gwas.data)]
# REMOVE SUFFIX
names(newgwas.data) <- gsub("_A", "", names(newgwas.data))
# RESET FACTORS
newgwas.data$A1 <- as.factor(newgwas.data$A1)
newgwas.data$A2 <- as.factor(newgwas.data$A2)
```

Comment: I like this answer a lot. Another thing my loop does though is that it gives a negative sign to the zscore column, how could this be done with your method?

Comment: Add line to comparedf equations. See edit. However, since I see one data point already with a negative sign, I condition with another `ifelse()`. Do same for other needed calculations in the comparedf area.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! I'm confused. And I'm sorry I gave a bad explanation to you. I want the zscore to have it's sign flipped only when I change the MAF to (1-MAF), does that make sense?

Comment: Got it. Simply use same condition as before in another `ifelse()` and multiple zscore by -1.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the best answer